# When two views are in the same place, how to control which show and which hide?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiview-hierarchy

when two views' areas are overlap, how to control which view show and which was hidden by the other ,thank you.I search the interfacebuild,  no options can solve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to do this programmatically you can call:

`[view bringSubviewToFront:subview]`
and
`[view sendSubviewToBack:subview]`.

in *Interface Builder* you can control this with:

`select view --> Editor --> Arrange --> Send forward/backward/to front/to back` (see screenshot)

[image]

Comment: @leizh007 great! :) can you please tick the green arrow then :)